# Fullcalendar event selection that spans midnight?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar with jQuery:

I create an event selection with...

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('select',startDate,endDate,false);

... where startDate is a date object before midnight (say, 9pm on Tuesday) and endDate is a date object after midnight (say, 9am on the following Wednesday).  The method call executes without error, but only the "pre-midnight" portion of the selection renders on the calendar.  Is it possible to have a selection that spans midnight render correctly, i.e. with both the pre- and post-midnight portions of the selection visible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

that is currently a limitation with the selection code. can you enter a bug report on the official issue tracker?

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list

thanks